# Authentication in Fitnesse not working for WebPages

Tags: java, authentication, automation, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I had created a FitnesseAuthentication.txt with following text:

```
!fitnesse.authentication.HashingCipher
admin:UqKBNj590CeI3kOLiZXL
```

And I used this file while running the fitnesse server as follows:

```
java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -r /wiki -e 0 -a FitnesseAuthentication.txt
```

**The Server started and then I tried to access the webpage using localhost, the webpage allowed me to run the suit without any authentication.** Is this correct way to authenticate the fitnesse server?

Comment: I am also doing similar thing , Checking the check-boxes in the properties file did not have any effect. Did you figure out how to authenticate access to fitnesse?

Comment: nope. we skipped it.

Answer (score 0):

For parent web page you need to enable secure-read/secure-write/secure-execute

You can do it by going to the parent page --> Properties --> Under security
Check all the three check-boxes

[Security Check Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFnim.png)